# Writing to XML file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to write to a xml file using jQuery?

This is my directory

```
- root
    - css
        popup.css
    - js
        jquery.js
        ajax.js
    - xml
        data.xml
    popup.html
    popup.js
    manifest.json
```

my `ajax.js` reads the xml data and checks if the particular person is registered, if it is, it alerts the user that the username is taken, else i want to register that person on `data.xml` file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var account = [];

    $.ajax ({
        url: 'xml/data.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        type: 'get',
        cache: 'false',

        success: function ( xml ) {
            // :: Pushing Registered People in Account Array
            $(xml).find('record').each(function(){
            account.push({
                    username: $(this).find('username').text(),
                    master: $(this).find('master').text()
                });
            });

            // :: When Submit Button is Clicked
            $('#submitReg').click(function(){
                var found = false;
                for ( i=0; i<account.length && !found; ++i ) {
                    if ( account[i]['username'] == $('#usr').val() ) found = true;
                }

                // :: If Username Already Exists
                if ( found ) {
                    $('#errorStatus').html('Username Already Exists');
                    $('#usr').val('');
                    $('#pwd').val('');
                }
                else {
                    // :: Write to file
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Files are local and aren't hosted, so i won't be using PHP or ASP.NET for any manner. (EDIT: i.e i want my `data.xml` to be stored on a computer/laptop/device on who ever is using this extension).

my `data.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<details>
    <record>
        <username>Danyal Imran</username>
        <master>1982gonzopracontroli</master>
    </record>

    // :: ADD MORE RECORDS HERE 

</details>
```

I want newly Registered Username and Master(Password) be wrapped in a xml format and written to `data.xml`

Registration Page:

```
<div id="registrationPanel"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter Desired Username">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Master Password">
</div>
```

Comment: you want to save the xml on the server?

Comment: no, on the computer/device who is using the plugin. @Natrium

Comment: can this help you? https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: Saving username/password in plain text is a bad idea from a security point of view.  This is particularly true if you are intending to have a list of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension's directory is read-only for the extension, and the rest of the filesystem is not even readable.

Note that if you try to change any files there on a non-development install, Chrome will immediately consider that the extension was tampered with and permanently disable it - it saves cryptographically signed hashes of all files. So, it's not possible to install-then-configure the extension via a file.

You should store your data in some other storage: for instance, `chrome.storage`. If you need to provide a way to export data as a file, you can use `chrome.downloads` API for it.

Note that Chrome does *not* provide a safe, encrypted storage accessible from an extension.